# How to handle NULL values in IF ELSE block in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an HTTP Trigger output - body() ,for which I'm trying to filter NULL values.

I'm trying body() *is not equal* to NULL, Is there any Expression for handling NULLs ?

[image: IF ELSE Bloack]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/coalescefunction) function within logic app expression to check for null or empty array value.  coalesce function will always return you non-null values so you can compare with empty array []

```
@coalesce(body('List_Records_2')['value'][0]?['sample'], 'Japan')
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't get the ['sample'], 'Japan' part, is that optional ?

Comment: Yes that's optional default val